# Esperanto cursive writing

Tags: writing

What is the generally approved way to write in cursive in Esperanto?

Most likely all standard letters are written in the same way as in English (are they?)

What are the best practices of writing "ĉapelitaj" letters and "ŭ"?

Comment: I do not know of any norm (as opposed to braille and steno). If you are coming from a non-latin script like Cyrillic one should avoid typical errors like a `k` that looks like a smaller `K` and so on. English style writing will do.

Comment: @JoopEggen If you have an answer, please post it below. Answers posted in comments do not have the features to assure vetting and on-going improvement of this content... so when it looks like the author has been helped, folks don't realize the question is still "unanswered" for everyone else who may be searching for this content. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino thanks, "I do not know of any norm" would probably haven been both sufficient and a real comment. As I do not think someone can give an answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sometimes *"there is no answer"* can actually be *the answer,* if you can say so somewhat authoritatively. Guessing in comments is the worst of both possible worlds (i.e. wrong[?] information  + no vetting)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the example of the script alphabet that appears in the *Fundamento* on page 46 (see this [PDF version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3bwzubbm6ecMU50OUtTamdSa1k/edit)):

[image: Alfabeto de Esperanto]

Of course, this particular font was done with a printing press, and everyone does it a little differently anyway, partly based on their native country and language, and partly just because everyone's handwriting is different. Any cursive form of the Latin alphabet will do, as there is enough commonality between different handwriting styles of that alphabet that the letters are still recognizable. But we can see from this example, that the diacritics are added separately, after the rest of the letter (and presumably the word) is completed. Which is how it is done in most languages, so that isn't surprising.

Of course there are people who can't read cursive, and those who can't write it legibly, but that is an issue with cursive in general, not Esperanto in particular. At least Esperanto is (mostly) free of the infamous "Q"! :-D

Answer (score 13):

I have a strong suspicion that the answer is simply that there is no standard for cursive handwriting and people write using whatever method they already know for the Latin alphabet. We can however get some examples of cursive writing by doing a Google search for “Esperanto postcard”.

From Finland:

[image: postcard from Finland]

From England:

[image: postcard from England]

From France:

[image: postcard from France]

It looks like in these examples the authors simply return to the word later to add the circumflexes as they would for the dots on the i’s.

Answer (score 9):

There is no norm, which is a problem. That problem can really only be realistically solved by avoiding cursive writing in Esperanto.

Comment: lol. This is really funny.

Comment: How is there a problem? There is a general similarity of cursive forms of Latin letters between different languages, and I find all the postcards in Neil's answer perfectly legible (well, except where that crazy UEA logo gets in the way). In fact, I don't see any more difference between one and another of those, than between my cursive writing and that of my friend, or my uncle, even though we live in the same country and speak the same language.

Answer (score 1):

It is done exactly like the English cursive scripts with the diacritic markings (ĉapelitoj) unslanted.

Answer (score 0):

Mi dirus skribu ĝin kiel en la Angla poste aldoni la diakritikoj (kiel Marcus Trawick diris). I would say write it like in English then add the diacritics (like Marcus Trawick said).